# Is it possible to give a promo code for a paid Mac App (no in-app purchases)

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, mac-app-store

I have a paid [app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/dark-reader-for-safari/id1438243180) and I would like to give some users free access.

I have no in-app purchases and the **Features** tab in **App Store Connect** says *"Promo Codes can only be generated for approved versions"*.

How do I generate a promo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have a *released* version of your app it should be listed in the **Features** tab, the message you are seeing suggests your app is not yet approved and available for purchase. Just wait until it is. HTH

Edit: The link in your question did not work for me so I assumed the app was not approved. However I just found it by searching the App Store. It has only just been released, the **Features** tab is probably lagging a bit, as before just wait a while and it should appear.

Comment: I updated the link, "en/" part stopped working. I was able to purchase my own app today.

Comment: My fault, I had to put "1" into text box below "100", not very intuitive though.